# Why is $\int \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

I have to show that for $f: [0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, we have$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\log(2)$$ I don't understand why $$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
Could someone please explain?

Comment: What is the definition of $\chi_A(x)$ for a set $A$? In particular, since $\chi \ge 0$, we can split $\int _0^{\infty}$ into $\int_A + \int_{[0,\infty)\setminus A}$.

Comment: Well, in which sense your integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ is defined? If it is in Lesbeque sense then I'm pretty sure this integral doesn't exist.

Comment: If it is defined in the improper sense, then there is the following equality which will be useful for your demonstration.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}  \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{2}{2k}=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n} $$

Comment: Also, it is clear by the definition of improper integral that your last equality holds

Comment: The Lebesgue integral does indeed not exist. Sadly, I don't really know what your getting at. It's not obvious for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any integer $N>0$, if $x>N$, $\chi_{[n-1,n)}=0$ for $x\le N$ and hence
$$ \int \limits_{0}^{N}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\int \limits_{0}^{N}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$$
Then letting $N\to\infty$, we have
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\chi_{[n-1,n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$$